# Copy to clipboard without Flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I found many solutions for copying to the clipboard, but they all either with flash, or for websites side.
I'm looking for method copy to clipboard automatically, without flash and for user side, it's for userscripts and of course cross-browser.

Comment: Haven't found any, been looking for same thing. Did want to use Flash either thus removed this feature prior creation.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Without using FLASH I doubt you can get it done in various browsers. But there are concrete solution available that can help you get the solution [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)

Comment: Rakesh - your "concrete solution" is based on Flash. It wont work in any browser I use.

Comment: @wizztjh method in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript is for site side not for user side @Rakesh zeroclipboard is good but i want to find method completely without Flash

Comment: I have heard that support for zeroclipboard has been dropped, so it's most likely a new solution will come up

Comment: Try this: https://clipboardjs.com/

Answer (score 31):

Without flash, it's simply not possible in most browsers. The user's clipboard is a security-relevant resource since it could contain things like passwords or credit card numbers. Thus, browsers rightly don't allow Javascript access to it (some allow it with a warning shown that the user has confirm, or with signed Javascript code, but none of that is cross-browser).

Comment: So maybe pages shouldn't be able to read from the clipboard, but why not write to it? =/

Comment: But then why allow it to happen through an hidden flash that involves zero user notification and feedback?

Comment: @EricGrange: Because back in the mid 1990s someone at Netscape decided that for performance reasons, browser plugins would be native binaries and thus able to do pretty much anything. The online world was a far simple place back then, and security not that much of a concern.

Comment: While this answer was true in 2011, browsers have come a long way in the fight to kill flash.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 26):

I had tryed the flash solution and I don't liked too. Too complex and too slow. What I did was to create a textarea, put the data into that and use the browser "CTRL + C" behavior.

The jQuery javascript part:

```
// catch the "ctrl" combination keydown
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(!args) args=[]; // IE barks when args is null
        if(e.keyCode == key && e.ctrlKey) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
            return false;
        }
    });
};

// put your data on the textarea and select all
var performCopy = function() {
    var textArea = $("#textArea1");
    textArea.text('PUT THE TEXT TO COPY HERE. CAN BE A FUNCTION.');
    textArea[0].focus();
    textArea[0].select();
};

// bind CTRL + C
$.ctrl('C'.charCodeAt(0), performCopy);
```

The HTML part:
    `<textarea id="textArea1"></textarea>`

Now, put what do you want to copy in 'PUT THE TEXT TO COPY HERE. CAN BE A FUNCTION.' area.
Works fine for me me. You just have to make one CTRL+C combination. The only drawback is that you are going to have an ugly textarea displayed in you site. If you use the style="display:none" the copy solution will not work.

Comment: This seems to only bind the function of Ctrl+C to a javascript function and not place the data in the OS clipboard.

Comment: sure, thats the idea. Make the browser copy for you. There is a similar solution here: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/clickCounter.html . When you double-click they create a text-area by javascript with the content.

Comment: did not work for me on osx so I added `e.metaKey` in the keydown comparison, but for some reason, copy action isn't triggered. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/gta67/1/

Comment: @GabLeRoux the copy function in safari is only enabled when text is selected. This did work previously but an update to safari recently has stopped it. It seems that selecting the text after the key down event is called just doesn't cut it in that browser any more. Still works fine in chrome however. Oh well, might have to fall back to using flash just for that browser....

Comment: Like this. When you can't hide (for any reason) a element that you don't need to see, you can always put far away from start, like padding-bottom: -1000.

Comment: Please check for http://jsfiddle.net/fbgkc3p1/.
This script does NOT that you say. Just copies a text into a field, but not into clipboard. Im doing something wrong?

Comment: @erm3nda this post is old. it seems that no longer works, indeed. :(

Comment: @julioS Yes, finally i've succesfull used zClip. Thx.

Answer (score 16):

[clipboard.js](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/#example-action) has just been released to copy to clipboard without the need of Flash

See it in action here > http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/#example-action

Answer (score 10):

**It's finally here!** (As long as you don't support Safari or IE8... -_- )

You can now actually handle clipboard actions without Flash.  Here's the relevant documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#copy

Answer (score 3):

<sup>While **waiting impatiently** for Xbrowser support of the [Clipboard API](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/)...</sup>

---

This will work beautifully in  **Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE**

**IE** will only prompt the user once to access the Clipboard.
**Safari** (5.1 at the time of writing) [does not support `execCommand` for `copy/cut`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

```js
/**
 * CLIPBOARD
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/33337109/383904
 */
const clip = (val) => {  
  const area = document.createElement("textarea");
  area.value = val;
  document.body.appendChild(area);
  area.select();
  if(document.execCommand('copy')) console.log("Copied to clipboard");
  else prompt("Copy to clipboard:\nSelect, Cmd+C, Enter", cont); // Saf, Other
  area.remove();
};


[...document.querySelectorAll(".clip")].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    clip(evt.currentTarget.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<a class="clip" href="#!">Click an item to copy</a><br>
<a class="clip" href="#!"><i>Lorem</i></a><br>
<a class="clip" href="#!"><b>IPSUM</b></a><br>

<textarea placeholder="Paste here to test"></textarea>
```

All browsers (except Firefox which is able to only handle mime type `"plain/text"` as far as I've tested) have **not implemented** the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/ClipboardEvent). I.e, trying to read the clipboard event in Chrome using

```js
var clipboardEvent = new ClipboardEvent("copy", {
  dataType: "plain/text",
  data: "Text to be sent to clipboard"
});
```

throws: **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor**

The best resource of the **unbelievable mess** that's happening among browsers and the Clipboard can be seen [here (caniuse.com)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard) (→ Follow the comments under *"Notes"*).
MDN says that basic support is *"(YES)"* for all browsers which is inaccurate cause one would expect at least the API to work, at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clipboard local to the HTML page. This allows you to copy/cut/paste content WITHIN the HTML page, but not from/to third party applications or between two HTML pages.

This is how you can write a custom function to do this (tested in chrome and firefox):

**Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eatchocolate/t91qsvah/) that demonstrates how you can do this.**

I will also paste the fiddle here for reference.

---

**HTML**

```
<p id="textToCopy">This is the text to be copied</p>
<input id="inputNode" type="text" placeholder="Copied text will be pasted here" /> <br/>

<a href="#" onclick="cb.copy()">copy</a>
<a href="#" onclick="cb.cut()">cut</a>
<a href="#" onclick="cb.paste()">paste</a>
```

---

**JS**

```
function Clipboard() {
    /* Here we're hardcoding the range of the copy
    and paste. Change to achieve desire behavior. You can
    get the range for a user selection using
    window.getSelection or document.selection on Opera*/
    this.oRange = document.createRange();
    var textNode = document.getElementById("textToCopy");
    var inputNode = document.getElementById("inputNode");
    this.oRange.setStart(textNode,0);
    this.oRange.setEndAfter(textNode);
    /* --------------------------------- */
}

Clipboard.prototype.copy = function() {
    this.oFragment= this.oRange.cloneContents();
};

Clipboard.prototype.cut = function() {
    this.oFragment = this.oRange.extractContents();
};

Clipboard.prototype.paste = function() {
    var cloneFragment=this.oFragment.cloneNode(true)
    inputNode.value = cloneFragment.textContent;
};

window.cb = new Clipboard();
```

Comment: Hey mtBrona. Is there a way u will attach some jsfiddle for this one? Cannot seems to activate it

Comment: Can we pass string here in place of elemnt

Comment: This works only is you're inside the same `window`. It's **not an actual Clipboard** available to the OS and another browser tab. Also the selection can be easily done using `select()` and than simply `window.getSelection()`

Answer (score 0):

`document.execCommand('copy')` will do what you want. But there was no directly usable examples in this thread without cruft, so here it is:

```
var textNode = document.querySelector('p').firstChild
var range = document.createRange()
var sel = window.getSelection()

range.setStart(textNode, 0)
range.setEndAfter(textNode)
sel.removeAllRanges()
sel.addRange(range)
document.execCommand('copy')
```

Answer (score -2):

There is not way around, you have to use flash. There is a JQuery plugin called [jquery.copy](http://yangshuai.googlepages.com/jquerycopyplugin) that provided cross browser copy and paste by using a flash (swf) file. This is similar to how the syntax highlighter on my blog works.

Once you reference the jquery.copy.js file all you need to do to push data into the clipboard is run the following:

```
$.copy("some text to copy");
```

Nice and easy ;)

Comment: Link broken (the files are no longer up for download)