# Copy to clipboard with no Flash - Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy to clipboard without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355300/copy-to-clipboard-without-flash)

I want to copy some text from an element by a given id to clipboard. I want to be **flashless** solution, no Flash at all. It can be in jQuery or JavaScript.

The solution for IE is simple (clipboardData), but for FF, Chrome and others - it doesn't work.

Help.

Comment: jQuery is *not* Javascript -- it's a client-side Javascript framework

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no javascript method to do this - its prevented by browser security ... Flash is the best alternative ...

Explanation of security policy on Firefox -> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard

Comment: this is garbage... how does chrome say "this is a security problem so we won't implement it, but we will bundle flash with our browser which allows it to happen anyways"

Comment: This is false. The Clipboard API is a work in progress standard, being currently implemented by Firefox with the other browsers pending - http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html#widl-ClipboardEvent-clipboardData

Comment: Clipboard API now works in Chrome and Firefox (but not Safari AFAIK) - example here: http://codepen.io/nottrobin/pen/meObWe