# Copy to Clipboard Link? closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Update**

Since browsers prohibit it, I'm going to leave it. It's no big deal. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) ?

Comment: You can use [jQuery to get the hex code of your background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery) & [copy it to the Clipboard on click using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript) ([take a look here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)) to achieve your goal.

Comment: or Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355300/copy-to-clipboard-without-flash

Comment: Tried those, didn't work. The only option would be to use Flash so no problem, it's not a big deal if I don't use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there's no universal browser-only solution for this. The browser security model explicitly prohibits access to local client's clipboard (though some browsers, like Netscape, have ways around that).

Using a non-browser code (like flash or similar methods) is the only way to do it in a cross-browser implementation.

Comment: I get ya, I thought it was possible but seems not, no worries, thanks anyway!