# Copy to clipboard in javascript doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7"];
            var ids = ["76561199144601203", "76561199085110484", "76561199202629307", "76561198977492126", "76561199107090117", "76561199156985347", "76561199195037086"];
            var part = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
                $('#user_id_table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><th scope="row">' + usernames[i] + '</th><td><button onclick="CopyIdToClipboard(' + ids[i] + ')">' + ids[i] + '</button></td></tr>');
            }
        });

        function CopyIdToClipboard(text) {
            // Create a temporary input element
            var $tempInput = $('<input type="text">');
            $('body').append($tempInput);

            // Set the value of the temporary input element to the text
            $tempInput.val(text).select();

            // Copy the text to the clipboard
            document.execCommand('copy');

            // Remove the temporary input element
            $tempInput.remove();

            alert("Copied the text: " + text);
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table border" id="user_id_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">USERNAME</th>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is when I press the button to copy to clipboard, in the alert and in my clipboard there is a round up of the ID even if it is a string, the first two numbers change.
Example: The first one(76561199144601203) gives me this "76561199144601200"

It shouldn't change anything, it should only get copied to the clipboard.
I tried other approches like `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` but the result is the same.

What I'm doing wrong? Anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard You may need to `focus` on the element. You may also want to add `type='text'` to ensure it does not default to something else, like Number. If you want more help, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your input data (with two separate arrays) is quite odd. Use rather this data model: `const users = [{name:"foo", id:"123"}, {name:"bar", id:"987"}]` or rather: `const users = {123: {name:"foo"}, 987: {name: "bar"}}` since IDs are unique anyways.

Comment: **Your code works**... but you have a small typo: use Dev tools to debug your own code. Instead of `to_copy` you need to use `text` argument.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33337109/383904

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the typo is a copy (from code to StackOverflow) mistake related, I was changing code while I was creating the question here, it doesn't affect my problem, it still rounds down

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it isn't a duplicate, this is a copy problem not a how to copy. I tried every method demostrated in that post an they gives me the same result

Comment: @Twisty I added a "code snippet". I tried adding **type='text'** but gives me the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some slight rework of the `CopyIdToClipboard` function to use the button element to get the text, try the runnable example below.

Basically the changes are all in the javascript handling:

1. In the loop where the buttons are added, the `onclick` event changes to: `onclick="CopyIdToClipboard(this)"` ... (`this` is a reference to the button element itself)
2. The parameter to `CopyIdToClipboard` changes from `text` to `element` (as it is now an element reference, and not text)
3. To the `val()`, the button element's `textContent` is set as the value. (the button's text)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7"];
            var ids = ["76561199144601203", "76561199085110484", "76561199202629307", "76561198977492126", "76561199107090117", "76561199156985347", "76561199195037086"];
            var part = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
                $('#user_id_table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><th scope="row">' + usernames[i] + '</th><td><button onclick="CopyIdToClipboard(this)">' + ids[i] + '</button></td></tr>');
            }
        });

        function CopyIdToClipboard(element) {
            // Create a temporary input element
            var $tempInput = $('<input type="text">');
            $('body').append($tempInput);

            // Set the value of the temporary input element to the text
            $tempInput.val(element.textContent).select();
                     // note that .innerHTML works too

            // Copy the text to the clipboard
            document.execCommand('copy');

            // Remove the temporary input element
            $tempInput.remove();

            alert("Copied the text: " + element.innerHTML);
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table border" id="user_id_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">USERNAME</th>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```